# Check digit MSSQL function: remove letters

Tags: sql, sql-server

A simple check digit function. For example, when digit to be checked is `"123456789012"`, the result is `"8"`.

However, some results in the column contain letters too. For example, when the result is `"abc123456789012"`, it should remove the `"abc"`, and just calculate the numbers.

How can I do that in the same function?

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.CheckdigitVoucher
(
  @ACode AS VARCHAR(12)
)
RETURNS INTEGER
AS BEGIN

  RETURN (10 - (CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 1, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + 3* CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 2, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 3, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + 3* CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 4, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 5, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + 3* CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 6, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 7, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + 3* CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 8, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 9, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + 3* CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 10, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 11, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + 3* CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 12, 1) AS INTEGER)
               )%10
         )%10
END;
```

Comment: Your code looks like MS SQL (SQL Server) code, not as MySQL one. Check your DBMS carefully.

Comment: Ok, even so, the solution would be similar.

Comment: Your code won't work with variable length strings - it assumes and depends on a fixed 12 character length. Fix that first. Next, your logic won't work if you pass "abc123456789012" since that is more than 12 characters and your function code cannot "see" anything past the character "9". You need to step back and think about your requirements and how to implement it properly in your environment.

Comment: You would do better to use a loop function incrementing a variable which is the charindex you are working on.

Comment: Please tag the _version_ of SQL Server you're using (you get this from `SELECT @@VERSION;`, not Help > About in Management Studio). Also, will the numeric portion of a string always be 12 characters? What do you want to happen if there are 16 digits or only 11 digits or 5 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like below can help and here's a [demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2599f8d63f5d8a1ff04fc64b2b3ce361)

we get all valid numbers in the digits cte, and explode out each valid character from input string into length cte followed by joining back all characters in the output cte

```
DECLARE @ACode  nvarchar(max)='abc123456789012'
; with digits as 
(
select 0 as valid, cast('0' as nvarchar) as v
union all
select c.valid+1 as valid, cast(c.valid+1 as nvarchar) as v  from digits c
where c.valid <9)
, length as 
(
select 0 as l,cast('' as nvarchar) as s 
union all
select c.l+1, coalesce(a.v,'') as s  from length c
outer apply 
(select v from digits where v =SUBSTRING(@Acode,l+1,1))a
where c.l <LEN(@Acode))
, output as
(
select 0 as p, cast('' as nvarchar(max)) as str
union all
select p+1 as p, concat(str,s) as str from length l join output o on o.p=l.l

)

select @ACode =str from output
where p = (select max(p) from output)

SELECT (10 - (CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 1, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + 3* CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 2, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 3, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + 3* CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 4, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 5, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + 3* CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 6, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 7, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + 3* CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 8, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 9, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + 3* CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 10, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 11, 1) AS INTEGER)
                + 3* CAST(SUBSTRING(@ACode, 12, 1) AS INTEGER)
               )%10
         )%10
```

Comment: Very good. Works perfectly on SQL server, but did not work in previous versions due to concat.

Comment: @CJava replace `concat(str,s) as str` with `isnull(str,'') +s as str `

Answer (score 1):

We can create a function which loops through the string passed in parameter, checks whether each character is a digit, and adds it to the variable to be returned if it is.

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.checkDigit (@rawValue NVARCHAR(100))
> RETURNS INT
> AS
> BEGIN
> DECLARE @i int = 0
> DECLARE @res int = 0
> DECLARE @this char(1)
> WHILE @i < LEN(@rawValue)
>   BEGIN
>     SET @i = @i + 1;
>     SET @this = SUBSTRING(@rawValue,@i,1);
>     SET @res = @res + CASE  WHEN @this LIKE '[0-9]' THEN @this ELSE 0 END
>   END
> SET @res = @res % 10
> return @res
> END
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT dbo.checkDigit('abc123456789012');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | ---------------: |
> |                8 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=def6bc3a2cb152d3487ce75913e68344)*

Answer (score 0):

You could re-write the function as a table-valued function like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetVoucherCheckDigits
(
  @ACode varchar(20)
)
RETURNS table WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN 
  (
      WITH n(n, s) AS 
      (
        SELECT 1,   SUBSTRING(@ACode, 1,   1) UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1, SUBSTRING(@ACode, n+1, 1) FROM n 
        WHERE n < LEN(@ACode)
      ),
      s(n,s) AS 
      (
        SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n),s
        FROM n WHERE TRY_CONVERT(tinyint, s) IS NOT NULL
      )
      SELECT CheckDigit = (10 - 
        SUM(s*CASE n%2 WHEN 0 THEN 3 ELSE 1 END)%10)%10 FROM s
  );
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=0221323b5861b639b6c7308d95a1c7ae)

This is much more efficient than a scalar UDF, removes the duplication of all those `3*` clauses, and allows you to handle non-numeric data all in one shot.

But really, you should fix the data, and add a constraint (e.g. `CHECK (col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%')` to prevent future bad data from getting in...